# How can I actually use a JAX-RS client configured with Spring?

Tags: java, spring, web-services, jax-rs, cxf

My application shall make calls to a REST service. So I added the package `cxf-rt-rs-client` from `org.apache.cxf` as a dependency.

In a `cxf.xml` configuration this is how I define my JAX-RS client:

```
<jaxrs:client id="myRestClient" serviceClass="org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.client.WebClient">
    <http-conf:authorization>
        <sec:UserName>testuser</sec:UserName>
        <sec:Password>myPassword</sec:Password>
        <sec:AuthorizationType>Basic</sec:AuthorizationType>
    </http-conf:authorization>
</jaxrs:client>
```

However I think I have missed a point. How do I actually use this client in ma Java code? There must be some mechanism which makes this `myRestClient` available in the application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is *tersely* documented in section [Injecting proxies of CXF JAX-RS Client API documentation](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/jax-rs-client-api.html#JAX-RSClientAPI-Injectingproxies). To be more explicit, the useful Java code for the XML example in this section can be found in the [class `org.apache.cxf.systest.jaxrs.jaxws.BookStoreSoapRestImpl` of CXF samples](https://github.com/apache/cxf/blob/master/systests/jaxrs/src/test/java/org/apache/cxf/systest/jaxrs/jaxws/BookStoreSoapRestImpl.java#L54).

So, in your case, I guess something like this:

```
@Resource(name = "myRestClient")
private org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.client.WebClient webClient;
```

Comment: For constructor injection the parameter can be annotated with `@Lazy @Qualifier("myRestClient")`.